# Apply css to datalist tag in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an input search box with autocompletion  where I am displaying array of names. I am using datalist tag. When sme names are typed in search text box it will give names present in the array. I am unable to change css of the array shown in dropdown.

*my component.html*

```
<input type="text" placeholder="select name"  (keyup)="arrayList($event.target.value)"
id="nameId" list="nameOptions"  formControlName="name">
<datalist id="nameOptions">
<option *ngFor="let name of names | async" [value]="name">
{{name}}
 </option>
</datalist>
```

I am trying to apply css as follows

*my component.css file*

```
datalist{
 position:absolute;
 max-height:50px;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:scroll
 }
```

Right now it is showing like below
[image: Below picture shows drop down list of array when we type in search text box]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
::ng-deep datalist{
     position:absolute;
     max-height:50px;
     overflow-x:hidden;
     overflow-y:scroll
 }
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: can you create a stackbliz link to provide a demo so I could help there.